# Late 70s-early 80s Pocket Books "Best of" science fiction author series, who was included?

Tags: short-stories, history-of

In the late 1970s - early 1980s there were at least two publishers putting out "The Best of" single author short story collections.

Del Rey was kind enough to provide a catalog of the books in the series on a page in the books, so I have that information.

I haven't been able to find a resource giving the titles in the Pocket Books series though.  Is there a resource somewhere that gives all the titles in this series?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you say "Del Rey" are you referring to the series [*Ballantine's Classic Library of Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubseries.cgi?2263)?  (The publisher was originally Ballantine, and then Del Rey/Ballantine.)

There is no comparable series entry on ISFDb for Pocket Books' collections, but [this ISFDb query](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=pub_ctype&O_1=exact&TERM_1=&C=AND&USE_2=pub_publisher&O_2=contains&TERM_2=pocket+books&USE_3=pub_title&O_3=contains&TERM_3=best+of&USE_4=pub_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=pub_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=pub_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=pub_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=pub_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=pub_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=pub_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=pub_year&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Publication) gives us:

- [*The Best of John Collier*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?881072) (1975)
- [*The Best of A. E. van Vogt*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?610165) (1976)
- [*The Best of Barry N. Malzberg*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37470) (1976)
- [*The Best of Damon Knight*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25560) (1976)
- [*The Best of Harry Harrison*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38177) (1976)
- [*The Best of Jack Vance*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25561) (1976)
- [*The Best of Keith Laumer*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36983) (1976)
- [*The Best of Mack Reynolds*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?26603) (1976)
- [*The Best of Poul Anderson*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?37715) (1976)
- [*The Best of Robert Silverberg*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?31231) (1976)
- [*The Best of Walter M. Miller Jr.*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25562) (1980)
- [*The Best of John Sladek*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38554) (1981)
- [*The Best of Randall Garrett*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?34007) (1982)
- [*The Best of Wilson Tucker*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?38550) (1982)

Note: I have updated the query to include books under other "Pocket Books" imprints like "Timescape / Pocket Books" and "Pocket Books / SFBC."

Comment: Thanks for the update!